# Preferred IDE for consuming webservices using PHP

Tags: php

I'm really new to PHP and wondered if there's a recommended IDE which makes working with SOAP web services easier. I know you can set up a proxy to a SOAP service with .asp and then get code completion when writing calls to the API. Is there anything like this for PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its not an IDE so much as it is a toolkit, but NuSOAP works really well for me and my PHP guys

http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/